# How can I get CRT file, KEY file and PFX file for the certificate where 'key' is not exportable?

Tags: c#, api, postman, ssl-certificate

I have created my certificate with the below configuration

```
 var key = RSA.Create();
 var publicParameters = key.ExportParameters(false);
```

it means I am requesting to export only the public key parameters of the RSA key pair. This means that the private key parameters, such as the private exponent, will not be included in the exported RSAParameters structure.

I would like to use `Postman` to call the API, but I am unable to attach the certificate to postman because postman requires the below values.

[image]

How can I get CRT file, KEY file and PFX file for the certificate where 'key' is not exportable?

I think we even can not even export as PEM file

[image]

Comment: If you could export the private key from a certificate where it's marked not exportable there would be no point in having the option. You'll need to recreate the certificate

Comment: Then how do we test our API's ?  do we need to attach the certificate programmatically? Postman does not support this feature?